# set NetworkImageView with Volley disable holder of the image

Tags: java, android, xml, android-volley, networkimageview

I use a adapter to load a lot of images witch have a holder, the problem when I scroll the image is loading and `NetworkImageView` holder is not shown anymore.

in adapter I use `setImageUrl` to set content of image

```
holderElementGridView.drawable2.setImageUrl(url,VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader());
```

and xml:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/iphone_feuilledematch_imagebackground" >
</com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>
```

the `iphone_feuilledematch_imagebackground` is disable when volley download image.

How can I keep the default drawable source until volley finish the download of drawable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of Volley, it works the way you want.

Comment: I have already integrate Volley in a lot of class, change to piccaso will take me a lot of time

Thank's for your reponses anyway